# pycharm packages not displayed in the project interpreter window

Tags: import, pycharm, package

I am using pycharm 5.0.4 community edition. 
I wanted to install package fuzzywuzzy. 
But when i go to project interpreter window and try to install package, it shows me no available packages. 
Can it be issue because I am using my work desktop.

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGoTR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details-  Are you not able to see any packages? Try searching for some other packages like pip, matplotlib, django, numpy etc. Sometimes it takes time for the IDE to build skeletons before you can actually start installing the packages. So once the IDE wait for it to complete its setup and then try to access the installation packages available.

Also if you do you have any other python interpreter installed on your local machine? If so then try switching to that interpreter.

Comment: Hi,  I do not see any packages as you can see from the image I has attached. Are you suggesting to change the interpreter ?

Comment: When you go to Settings>Project Interpreter, do you see any installed packages or libraries? If not then there is a pop-up which you should see at the bottom which says "Install packaging tools". Click on that and you will start seeing the libraries which are installed. Then click on add (+) button and you will reach the page where you can see the libraries/packages available for installation.   If not then change to another interpreter

Comment: Hi, When I changed the interpreter I was able to see the packages. But I still don't see package fuzzywuzzy. What might be the reason. Why is is that one interpreter shows the packages and other doesn't.

Comment: With the new interpreter you said you can see the available modules but not fuzzywuzzy. Do check what the dependency of fuzzywuzzy is and then try again. There might be an installation error or a lack visibility in the previous python interpreter which could cause such error in terms of not displaying the available modules. The dependency of fuzzywuzzy is available here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy . Hope this helps and please upvote if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some steps you can try, which worked for me:

Step-1 Activate your intelpython using:

```
source <your installation path>/bin/activate
```

Step-2 Clone the environment using conda clone command and make sure the pwd is ~/:

```
conda create -n <source_environment> --clone <destination_environment>
```

Step-3 Activate the cloned environment:

```
source ~/.conda/envs/<your_environment>/bin/activate
```

Step-4 Provide read-wite permissions to intelpython and cloned enviroment using:

```
sudo chown -R <user_name>:<group_name> /<path_to_directory i.e. /opt/intel and ~/.conda/envs>
```

Step-5 Open Pycharm and in System Interpreter add the path to above created enviroment and then you can use pip or Pycharm itself, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using the [Intel python distribution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python), and installing packages required write permissions to the folder that intelpython was installed in, which in my case was `/opt/intel/intelpython2`.

Try adding write permissions to the folder using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R <username> </path/to/folder>
```

Then try adding missing packages and/or repositories as seen in this page - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html.